# React' useEffect is causing infinite rendeing when the dependency has not changed

Tags: reactjs

I am working on React. I am having following component

```js
export default function ShowUsers() {
  const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([]);
  const classes = useStyles();
  // userData function returns array of components after fetching data from server with a GET request.
  // I have passed setUsers function to set the value of users after fetching from server. 
  var userData = GetUserData(classes, setUsers, users);
  useEffect(() => {
    setUsers(userData);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div style={divStyle}>
      {userData}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This code is calling the `GetUserData` function and making the `GET` request infinitely.
Could you please help me to find what is wrong in this code and if someone can just explain the cause and solution with a little explanation, I would be greatful.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you calling `GetUserData` from the component body and not inside the `useEffect`?

Comment: `GetUserData` gets passed `setUsers` as an argument, so it's very likely that it is calling that function. If that's true, then you will get a re-render - and since you're calling `GetUserData` from the component body it will call it again - and so on infinitely.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I would like to understand, how https://stackoverflow.com/a/67360797/9409824 is different than your suggestion?

Comment: Because in that answer they are only **declaring** a function in the body. You are **calling** a function in the body.

Comment: Also that answer was downvoted and has issues, so I'm not sure why it's being used as support...

Comment: So, what would be the working solution in this scenario?

Comment: Call the function from *inside* the `useEffect`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But how would I use the userData for rendering?

Comment: You're putting it in state, just use the state const instead of the direct result of the function call.

Comment: Yes, I got your point. But actually I am not able to access the `classes, setUsers, users` variables inside the useEffect callback.

Comment: They are within scope, so there's probably something else going on here. I'm not sure what `GetUserData` does, but the code you've provided doesn't make a lot of sense.. Why pass `setUsers` and `users` to a function that returns the value you set to `users`? It seems like maybe the function does more than it needs too..